# How to install Oracle database 11g on Ubuntu Server

Tags: oracle, ubuntu-server

I am using Ubuntu server 14.04 and I tried to find how to install oracle database 11g but could not found.

Do you have any suggestion or tutorial to guide that job?

Comment: shall i provide installation for server 12.0?

Comment: @utility: it's ok. Can you share me?

Comment: @Luc are you able to install Oracle 11g on Ubuntu Server

Comment: @twister_void: Here is what you need, pls check file `setup.sh` https://github.com/wnameless/docker-oracle-xe-11g/tree/master/assets

Answer (score 1):

To install the Oracle 11g database on Ubuntu, first download Ubuntu with a generic kernel from Ubuntu, and then release the link.

Installing on 12.0 is explained [here](http://blog.whitehorses.nl/2014/03/18/installing-java-oracle-11g-r2-express-edition-and-sql-developer-on-ubuntu-64-bit/)

Answer (score 0):

Another aproach is to setup a docker container with Oracle 11g.
Since Ubuntu is not a supported operating system, in can be much easier.

Here are the steps to install Oracle 11g Enterprise Edition:

### I. Firstly install docker (if not installed) :

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg-agent software-properties-common`
3. `curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -`
4. `sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"`
5. `sudo apt-get update`
6. `sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io`

(source https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository)

### II. Download and extract database files

7. Download Oracle installation files 
   https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/112010-linx8664soft.html
8. Unzip both files so you have a single "database" folder. Place this "database" folder somewhere and name it e.g "installation_folder"

### III. Setup docker container:

9. `sudo docker pull jaspeen/oracle-11g`
10. `sudo docker run --privileged --name oracle11g -p 1521:1521 -v /path/to/installation_folder:/install jaspeen/oracle-11g`

### IV. Use it. E.g. connect with SqlDeveloper (port 1521, SID orcl), or use sqlplus:

11. `sudo docker ps -a`
    Get container [YOUR_CONTAINER_ID]
12. `sudo docker exec -it [YOUR_CONTAINER_ID] /bin/bash`
13. `su - oracle`
14. `sqlplus / as sysdba`